# How can I validate the user input?

Tags: javascript, html

The program breaks if there's a space behind the last number entered. How can I stop the function from breaking if a space is entered? I tried $.trim but couldn't figure out how to get that to work. Also tried an if/else statement

```js
function calculate() {
    var numInput = document.getElementById("qty").value;
    var numArray = numInput.split(" ").map(function(t) {
        return parseInt(t);
    });

    var minValue = Math.min.apply(null, numArray);
    var maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
    var sumValue = numArray.reduce(function(previous, current) { return previous + current });
    var productValue = numArray.reduce(function(previous, current) { return    previous * current });
    var meanValue = numArray.reduce(function(previous, current) { return previous + current / numArray.length });

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Min value is: ' + minValue + '<br>' + 'Max value is: '+ maxValue + '<br>' + 'Sum value is: ' + sumValue + '<br>' + 'Product value is: ' + productValue + '<br>' + 'Mean value is: ' +   meanValue; 
}

function clearAnswer(){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("qty").value = '';
}
```

```html
<h1> Problem JavaScript</h1> Enter 5 numbers with spaces in between each:
<input type="text" id="qty">  
<input type="button" id="go" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()">
<button type="reset" id="reset" onclick="clearAnswer()">Clear</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: which line is breaking?

Comment: if there's a space entered after the last number after calculate is clicked all results = NaN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried $.trim but couldn't figure out how to get that to work.

if you are using [jquery trim](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) then ensure that you have included jquery library first.

change

```
var numArray = numInput.split(" ").map(function(t) {
return parseInt(t);
});
```

to

```
var numArray = $.trim( numInput ).split(" ").map(function(t) {
  return parseInt(t);
});
```

or simply

```
var numInput = $.trim( document.getElementById("qty").value );
```

use `$.trim()` to trim the `numInput` first

**Edit:**

you don't really need to use jquery only for using trim function here, javascript itself has [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) method, which you can use.

Comment: thanks so much! before i was using $.trim in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

`$.trim` is a jquery function and it works by passing a parameter to `trim`, which will be trimmed. For instance:

```
$.trim(" a ")
```

will result in `"a"`

Your example would work like this

```
var numArray = $.trim(numInput).split(" ").map(function(t) {
    return parseInt(t);
});
```

if and only if jquery is defined, that is, you load the library. However, if you want jquery specifically for this purpose, then there is a pure JS function for this purpose as an alternative, called `trim`. That can be used like this:

```
var numArray = numInput.trim().split(" ").map(function(t) {
    return parseInt(t);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about the javascript function

Comment: @cSimms, you are welcome. If you do not need jquery, then trim() is the solution.